# "To be" or "Be"

Tags: grammar, verbs, be

Could you please tell me the difference between the verb **To be** and **Be**, in terms of their uses and meaning? Is there a relation between the two? Do they mean the same?

Comment: Have you consulted any grammar books? What did you find? Were you reading or writing something when you faced a problem differentiating the two forms?

Comment: A better place to ask is ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

1. "be" is the original format of the am/are/is/was/were/been/being (infinitive)
2. "to be" is to+be (to infinitive-infinitive here is "be")
   "to be" is used as below.

**as noun**

To be a teacher is my dream.

**as adjective**

A student to be an English teacher should study hard.

**as adverb(for purpose)**

You should study hard to be an English teacher.

3. infinitive(here "be") is used as below.

Be ambitious. Be happy. Be quiet. Be ready. Be there. Be here. Be a mother.
Be a man. Be a fast runner. (imperative sentence)

"be" changes to **is**(he/she/it for present tense), **was**(he/she/it for past tense), **were**(they/you for past tense), **been**(I have been, You have been, They have been, She has been, He has been, It has been for present perfect tense and **had been** for past perfect like they had been, You had been, I had been, She had been, It had been)

Comment: I think you missed a couple of commas in your adjective example: "A student**,** to be an English teacher**,** should study hard."

Comment: @RonJohn, Thanks for the advice. Could you tell me why "without commas" is not good? I learnt it's okay. Could you show me some examples from the source we can believe?

Comment: You always use commas with "to" clauses.  For example, "A student should study hard." vs. "To be an English teacher, a student should study hard." vs. "To be an English teacher a student should study hard."

Comment: @RonJohn, At the moment  I don't agree with you. My sentence is different from yours and also you can rerfer to this : The next thing to be considered was food.

Comment: #1 "To be an English teacher, a student should study hard." is just a reordered version of "A student, to be an English teacher, should study hard." and so **is** the same.  #2 The "to be considered" sentence is substantively different, because "to be considered" is the main verb group, whereas "to be an English teacher" is not.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically speaking, "be" is an auxiliary verb, and "to be" is its infinitive format.

Regarding the meaning, both kind of mean the same. They can both convey the existence or occurrence of something, possessing a quality, or just simply show a particular tense without having an independent meaning.

- Her children have been asking a lot of questions.
- The old woman is more to be pitied than feared.